# sqlalchemy composite key error when cell run twice

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, pgadmin-4

My configuration cell contains the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io

def df_to_postgres(dataframe, table_name):

    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/postgres')
    df=dataframe
    
    df.head(0).to_sql(table_name.lower(), engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    
    conn = engine.raw_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    output = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
    output.seek(0)
    contents = output.getvalue()
    cur.copy_expert('COPY ' + table_name + ' FROM STDIN', output) 
    conn.commit()
```

and the cell uploading the dataframe has:

```
df_to_postgres(product_table,'final.product')
```

The product_table has a composite key which has been created in postgres. When I run it the 1st time everything is good, when I try the 2nd time I get:

```
UniqueViolation                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8004/2936867318.py in df_to_postgres(dataframe, table_name)
     15     output.seek(0)
     16     contents = output.getvalue()
---> 17     cur.copy_expert('COPY ' + table_name + ' FROM STDIN', output)
     18     conn.commit()

UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (sku, unit)=(000002, kg) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY product, line 1
```

I thought that if_exists='replace' would have solved this problem. Any solution?

Comment: I am going to say `output` has duplicate values over `(sku, unit)` in it.

Comment: I have checked, that is not the case. Even if it did, it would raise the error the first time. The table is successful in being uploaded the 1st time in to the database. When the cell is ran again is when the problem appears

Comment: Well you can take the error as truth and know that at some point the data is duplicated. Your best bet is too look at the Postgres logs and see what is actually hitting the database. I'm betting your process is not doing what you think it is, especially as regards cleaning the data of existing data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will keep looking. However, the fact that the error happens in the 1st observation of every table that has a composite key when the cell is ran twice, tells me that the error comes from elsewhere.